# Create MockService in soapUI without wsdl

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

Is it somehow possible to create mock service in soapUI without having wsdl file? All I have is sample request and responses. 
I think that should be possible to generate WSDL from request and response examples with soapUI but I'm not able to find any tutorials about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389568/how-to-use-soap-ui-without-wsdl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just with request/response you may not be able to construct the WSDL. If you have the end point URL, append '?wsdl' to the end point URL,open it in a browser, you should get the WSDL.

Also if you have the schema with you, you can try generating WSDL file from [here](http://www.theprogrammerfactory.com/)

Answer (score 7):

You can just trick SOAPUi with some dummy WSDL, at least with a single request/response definition! Just replace the requests it generates with the XML document you wanted. You an also add additional requests with entirely different request/responses by copy and pasting!