# how to use SoapUi without wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui

Is it possible to use SoapUI(Open Source version) without WSDL since I need to test few java functions which are available on server and I dont have WSDL for these functions?

Is it possible to create WSDL for these functions by any way?

Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: SoapUI supports multiple protocols such as SOAP, REST, HTTP, JMS, AMF and JDBC. Create RESTFul Webservices and test

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389568/how-to-use-soap-ui-without-wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have either `WSDL` path or service `end-point` address where you'll send the request. SoapUI can create the project and add operations from that end-point

Comment: Hi Learner, Thanks for your help. I have my Service end point in the format "http://www.example.com/project". Is it possible to to create project from this? If yes, How to create?

Comment: In `SoapUI`, go to File->New SoapUI project. In `Initial WSDL/WADL field: Enter your end-point path